# Object unidentify when using jqgrid.jqGridExport(), how to use it for exporting the grid in json

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, json, jqgrid

This is the javascript code i tried to export my grid data in json. it throws an exception and i can't figure out why. when i downloaded the jqgrid i checked the import/export module. 
I want to insert the json in a hidden field in order to get the data on the server side for validating and saving.

```
$('#proveObjekt2').val(JSON.stringify($("#rowed5").jqGridExport("jsonstring")));
...
<asp:HiddenField ID="proveObjekt2" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use parameters of `jqGridExport` in the wrong form. The parameter must be an object with three possible properties: `exptype`, `root` and `ident`. Because default values of the parameters are

```
{
    exptype : "xmlstring",
    root: "grid",
    ident: "\t"
}
```

the call `$("#rowed5").jqGridExport("jsonstring")` return XML instead of JSON. You should use

```
jQuery("#rowed5").jqGridExport({exptype:"jsonstring"})
```

or

```
jQuery("#rowed5").jqGrid('jqGridExport',{exptype:"jsonstring"})
```

instead.